# Moleculer js is not working on local server using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, moleculer

I am using Node.js. When I try to install Moleculer framework for Node.js Iget this error:

```
connect to server: Error:connect Econnrefused  xxx.0.0.1:xxxx
```

This are the commands I'm running:

```
npm install moleculer
npm install moleculer-cli -g
moleculer init project moleculer-demo
cd moleculer-demo
npm run dev
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you've answered `Yes` to all questions and getting this error then you've forgotten to start [NATS Server](https://nats.io/download/nats-io/nats-server/)